# How to implement RetrieveAttributeRequest via Odata?

Tags: c#, odata, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-webapi

In order to get OptionSet information, we can issue a request:

```
// Create the request
RetrieveAttributeRequest attributeRequest = new RetrieveAttributeRequest
{
    EntityLogicalName = Contact.EntityLogicalName,
    LogicalName = "new_string",
    RetrieveAsIfPublished = false
};

// Execute the request
RetrieveAttributeResponse attributeResponse =
    (RetrieveAttributeResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(attributeRequest);

Console.WriteLine("Retrieved the attribute {0}.",
    attributeResponse.AttributeMetadata.SchemaName);
```

**Is there a way to do this using an Odata request in crm 2016?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve all OptionSet values using OData in Dynamics CRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427389/retrieve-all-optionset-values-using-odata-in-dynamics-crm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, [Use the Web API with Dynamics 365 metadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt607833.aspx).

I suggest you look at the OptionSetMetadata, found at `[Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/GlobalOptionSetDefinitions`