# Can I use FetchXML to retrieve a list of Entities and a list of Attributes?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, fetchxml, dynamics-crm-365

I want a fetchxml that will return a list of Entities, hopefully with Display name and schema name.

Similarly I would like a fetchxml that will return the attributes for an Entity.  Also with Display name and Schema name.

I assume there is a way because tools in the XRMToolBox load dropdowns with those value.

Comment: If you want to try some cool tech to be able to use FetchXML to query metadata, you really should try this out! :) https://dreamingincrm.com/2018/06/14/using-virtual-entities-to-query-metadata/

Answer (score 2):

Fetchxml is DML query to retrieve data from backend & cannot be used for metadata retrieval. We have to use Organization service or web api to pull Metadata like Entity & attribute definitions.

SO [thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427389/retrieve-all-optionset-values-using-odata-in-dynamics-crm) & [thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43265140/how-to-retrieve-entity-names-in-crm-2016) will help you to achieve it.

Other useful links:

[Query metadata using the Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/query-metadata-web-api)

[Retrieve data with queries using SDK assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/retrieve-data-queries-sdk-assemblies)

[Use the Organization Service to read and write data or metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/use-organization-service-read-write-data-metadata)